# Code for staking Ethereum

Tags: solidity, contract-design, proof-of-stake, staking

Ethereum enabled staking for anyone with a minimum of 32 ETH. Where can I see the code of their staking protocol? Is it a .sol file? Is it a contract address whose code is viewable on Etherscan? Please include link, would like to understand how staking is programmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address can be obtained from different sites.

- https://docs.ethhub.io/ethereum-roadmap/ethereum-2.0/deposit-contract/
- https://ethereum.org/en/eth2/deposit-contract/

You can read the code from [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa#code).

There's a github repo https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/tree/dev/solidity_deposit_contract.

Comment: Where do staking funds get "deposited" to exactly

Comment: Besides the deposit function, which line of code does it explicate the reward/earnings of the staker (outflow for the contract rather than a deposit)?

Comment: @user610620 The deposit contract doesn't handle rewards, they are part of the eth2.0 consensus rules.

Comment: If the rewards for staking aren't handled in this deposit contract, what contract *does* handle the rewards for staking?

Comment: @user610620 There's no contract for rewards. The rewards are paid by the consensus rules of the beacon chain.

Comment: what are consensus rules of the "beacon chain"

Comment: @user610620 Last year the beacon chain was launched, eventually it will be ETH 2.0. The consensus rules are in this repo: https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs.

Comment: @user610620 It is working for me. Is the repo called `consensus-specs` in Ethereum's github. If you prefer reading code start by the eth2.0 clients [Teku](https://github.com/ConsenSys/teku), [prysm](https://github.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm), [lighthouse](https://github.com/sigp/lighthouse), etc.